# Place Wordpress posts pagination links at the bottom of the row in Bootstrap

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have numeric pagination links under a Wordpress `WP_Query` for my custom post type. But they are appearing within the Bootstrap `row` (like an extra column) instead of underneath the post.

Using Bootstrap 3.3.7

[image]

How can I move them to be displayed under the thumbnails on a new row?

I can't place them in a new `row` because then I'd have a row within a row. I tried creating a new class and set its position to absolute but that didn't work either.

The pagination links are within the loop, so they have to be inside the row.

```
<div class="row">

        <?php
        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
        // WP_Query arguments
        $args = array(
            'post_type'              => array( 'video' ),
            'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
            'nopaging'               => false,
            'posts_per_page'         => 3,
            'paged' => $paged
        );

        // The Query
        $video = new WP_Query( $args );

        // The Loop
        if ( $video->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $video->have_posts() ) {
                $video->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <figure class="snip1567">
                        <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Graphic Design</h3>
                            <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                        </figcaption>
                        <div class="hover"></div><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o"></i>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
                    </figure>
                </div>

            <?php } ?>

                <?php $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

                echo paginate_links( array(
                    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                    'total' => $video->max_num_pages
                ) );
                ?>

        <?php } else {
            // no posts found
        }

        // Restore original Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
```

CSS

```
/*
 * VIDEO THUMBNAIL STYLES
*/
.snip1567 {
    background-color: #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.snip1567 * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.snip1567 img {
    max-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.75;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.snip1567 figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.snip1567 h3 {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    background-color: #000000;
    top: 0;
    font-weight: 800;
    letter-spacing: -0.4px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.snip1567 p {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: right;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
    transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.snip1567 i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 54px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.snip1567 .hover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(1, 205, 116, 0.7);
    display: flex;
    font-size: 65px;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
}

.snip1567 a {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.snip1567:hover .hover,
.snip1567.hover .hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.snip1567:hover p,
.snip1567.hover p {
    opacity: 1;
}

.snip1567:hover h3,
.snip1567.hover h3 {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
}

.snip1567:hover i,
.snip1567.hover i {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.1);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0;
}

/*
 * PAGINATE LINKS
*/
.page-numbers {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    line-height: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.page-numbers.current,
a.page-numbers:hover {
    background: #f9f9f9;
}
```

HTML Output

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <figure class="snip1567">
                        <img src="http://localhost/technia/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/bb43432d-51b3-34c9-a4dc-3c6808e39651.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="How budget airlines work">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Graphic Design</h3>
                            <p>How budget airlines work</p>
                        </figcaption>
                        <div class="hover"></div><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o"></i>
                        <a href="http://localhost/technia/video/how-budget-airlines-work/"></a>
                    </figure>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <figure class="snip1567">
                        <img src="http://localhost/technia/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/5e47222d-3546-3958-acbd-c28df85b1c06.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Pompey">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Graphic Design</h3>
                            <p>Pompey</p>
                        </figcaption>
                        <div class="hover"></div><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o"></i>
                        <a href="http://localhost/technia/video/pompey/"></a>
                    </figure>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <figure class="snip1567">
                        <img src="http://localhost/technia/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/28b70c69-3f98-3fa3-b4ca-59acde889971.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Why are trains so expensive">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Graphic Design</h3>
                            <p>Why are trains so expensive</p>
                        </figcaption>
                        <div class="hover"></div><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o"></i>
                        <a href="http://localhost/technia/video/why-are-trains-so-expensive/"></a>
                    </figure>
                </div>


                <span class="page-numbers current">1</span>
                 <a class="page-numbers" href="http://localhost/technia/videos/page/2/">2</a>
                 <a class="next page-numbers" href="http://localhost/technia/videos/page/2/">Next »</a>

 </div>
```

Comment: can you post the html ..it would be much easier to debug.. Also is it bootstrap 3?

Comment: I've modified my original post and added the css and html output. Yes it's bootstrap 3.

Comment: check demo if snippet too below in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `.page_numbers` in a div with id `link_container` and style.
Apply a clear fix. example

```
#link_container{
clear: both;
padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Snippet below

```css
/*
 * VIDEO THUMBNAIL STYLES
*/

.snip1567 {
  background-color: #000000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.snip1567 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.snip1567 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.75;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.snip1567 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.snip1567 h3 {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  background-color: #000000;
  top: 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: -0.4px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.snip1567 p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.snip1567 i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 54px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.snip1567 .hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(1, 205, 116, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  font-size: 65px;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 0;
}

.snip1567 a {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.snip1567:hover .hover,
.snip1567.hover .hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.snip1567:hover p,
.snip1567.hover p {
  opacity: 1;
}

.snip1567:hover h3,
.snip1567.hover h3 {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.snip1567:hover i,
.snip1567.hover i {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.1);
  opacity: 0;
}


/*
 * PAGINATE LINKS
*/

.page-numbers {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 2px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  line-height: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.page-numbers.current,
a.page-numbers:hover {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

#link_container {
  clear: both;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <figure class="snip1567">
      <img src="https://www.nature.org/cs/groups/webcontent/@photopublic/documents/media/nick-hall-sichuan-province-537.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="How budget airlines work">
      <figcaption>
        <h3>Graphic Design</h3>
        <p>How budget airlines work</p>
      </figcaption>
      <div class="hover"></div><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o"></i>
      <a href="http://localhost/technia/video/how-budget-airlines-work/"></a>
    </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <figure class="snip1567">
      <img src="https://www.nature.org/cs/groups/webcontent/@photopublic/documents/media/nick-hall-sichuan-province-537.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Pompey">
      <figcaption>
        <h3>Graphic Design</h3>
        <p>Pompey</p>
      </figcaption>
      <div class="hover"></div><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o"></i>
      <a href="http://localhost/technia/video/pompey/"></a>
    </figure>
  </div>

  <!--<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="">
                        <div class="video-img" id="overlay">
                            <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-4x"></i>
                            <img class="img-responsive overlay" alt="" src="" />
                            <span></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="caption"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>-->

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <figure class="snip1567">
      <img src="https://www.nature.org/cs/groups/webcontent/@photopublic/documents/media/nick-hall-sichuan-province-537.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Why are trains so expensive">
      <figcaption>
        <h3>Graphic Design</h3>
        <p>Why are trains so expensive</p>
      </figcaption>
      <div class="hover"></div><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o"></i>
      <a href="http://localhost/technia/video/why-are-trains-so-expensive/"></a>
    </figure>
  </div>

  <div id="link_container">
    <span class="page-numbers current">1</span>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="http://localhost/technia/videos/page/2/">2</a>
    <a class="next page-numbers" href="http://localhost/technia/videos/page/2/">Next »</a>
    <div>

    </div>
```

[click her for demo with resizable window](http://codepen.io/repzeroworld/pen/zZgvzr)